# Place Google Map Marker icon using javascript taking images from Image asset in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi I am trying to set marker icon in Google Map using javascript. My image is in Images.xcassets. Right now I am doing this to set icon. But its not working for me. What I am doing is this:

```
setMarkerWithIcon('/Images/MapScreen/MapviewIcon/MapviewIcon');

function initialize(latitude, longitude, maxzoom) {
var styles = [{
          elementType: "labels",
          stylers: [
                    { visibility: "off" }
                    ]
          }];

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
                                              {name: "Styled Map"});

var mapOptions = {
zoom: initialZoomLevel,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude + LatLngDeltas[ randomIntFromInterval(0, LatLngDeltas.length) ],
                               longitude + LatLngDeltas[ randomIntFromInterval(0, LatLngDeltas.length) ] ),
disableDefaultUI: true,
disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
minZoom: initialZoomLevel,
maxZoom: maxzoom,
scrollwheel: false,
scaleControl: false,
rotateControl:true,
rotateControlOptions: {
position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER
},
mapTypeControl: false,
mapTypeControlOptions: {
mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
}
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                              mapOptions);

map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                              addMarker(map, event.latLng);
                              });
}

function addMarker(mapObject, location) {
deleteMarkers();
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: location,
                                    draggable:true,
                                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                                    map: mapObject,
                                    icon:markerPath
                                    });
setTimeout(function() {infowindow.open(mapObject,marker);}, 500);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                              infowindow.open(mapObject,marker);
                              });
markers.push(marker);
}

function setMarkerWithIcon(myIcon) {
markerPath = myIcon;
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is `markerPath` declared? Alternatively, you can try hosting the image somewhere and passing a URL instead, just to see if it works.

Comment: It works if I set an image like
    setMarkerWithIcon('MapviewIcon.png');
In this case this image is in the project bundle.